# Clamav freshclam not updating the db files

Tags: clamav

In my Linux system, I have installed clamav and clamav-daemon and updated the `Checks` parameter to `48` in the `freshclam.conf` (the db url points to a locally run private mirror)

The private mirror has the `cvdupdate` tool that is properly downloading the latest cvd files.

However, in the local machine, I have observed that neither the `cvd` files are updated nor the `freshclam.log` file is updated. But the downloads are successful if I run the `freshclam` command manually and the log file is also updated with the operations (all the operations are taking place with the `clamav` user itself).

May I know why is the auto update not happening? I was under the assumption that there need not be a separate cron job to run the `freshclam` command manually since we have the `Checks` parameters in the `freshclam.conf` file and the clamav/clamav-daemon takes care of updating the db files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `checks` has a different purpose but not for scheduling automatic updates. I had to schedule a cron job that executes the db update command using `freshclam` to update the virus definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the checks value you are putting in the freshclam.conf. freshclam db updates happens silently, if you want to get notified, you can use notify clamd parameter for getting the cvd files updates.

Comment: I had to schedule a cron job to run the clamav db updates using `freshclam` command